# Why does Deuteronomy 7:11 in [MT] show מִּצְוָה Mitsvah (s.) for "Commandments" (pl.), instead of Mitsvot , like "ἐντολὰς" [LXX]?

Tags: hebrew, textual-criticism, septuagint, authorial-intent, masoretic-text

If the word "Commandments" (plural) was actually meant to be written in [Deuteronomy 7:11], why does the [MT] show the singular word מִּצְוָה versus the [LXX] plural word ἐντολὰς?

[MT, Deuteronomy 7:11]
"You shall therefore, observe the-**commandment(s)**, the statutes, and the ordinances, which I command you this day to do." (וְשָֽׁמַרְתָּ֨ אֶת־הַמִּצְוָ֜ה וְאֶת־הַֽחֻקִּ֣ים וְאֶת־הַמִּשְׁפָּטִ֗ים אֲשֶׁ֨ר אָֽנֹכִ֧י מְצַוְּךָ֛ הַיּ֖וֹם לַֽעֲשׂתָֽם)

[LXX, Deuteronomy 7:11]
"καὶ φυλάξῃ τὰς **ἐντολὰς** καὶ τὰ δικαιώματα καὶ τὰ κρίματα ταῦτα ὅσα ἐγὼ ἐντέλλομαί σοι σήμερον ποιεῗν"

**Is מִּצְוָה a scribal error in Deuteronomy 7:11 [MT]?**

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a collective word for code or law; code of law or wisdom. [From Brown Driver Briggs:](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/4687.htm)

> 2 of God:
>
> a. singular the commandment, code of law: 2 Chronicles 8:13; Ezra
> 10:3; Psalm 19:9; especially of D ׳שׁמר המ Deuteronomy 8:1,25t. D;
> ׳עשׂח המ Deuteronomy 6:25; Deuteronomy 15:5; אשׁר צוּה ׳(ה)מ)
> Deuteronomy 26:13; Deuteronomy 30:11; Deuteronomy 31:5; ׳סוּר מִן המ
> Deuteronomy 17:20; הֵפַר ׳מ Numbers 15:31 (P); "" תּוֺרָה Exodus 24:12
> (RD) Joshua 22:5 (D) 2 Chron 14:3; 2 Chronicles 31:21; +חֻקִּים,
> מִשְׁמָּטִים Deuteronomy 5:28; Deuteronomy 6:1 +.
>
> b. plural of commands of D and later codes with 2 plural (ye shall,
> shall not; BrHex. new ed., 246 ff.), Leviticus 4:2 5t. P, Isaiah 48:18
> 25t. (late; especially Psalm 119:20 t.); ׳שׁמר מ Exodus 20:6 (R)
> Leviticus 22:31 (H) Deuteronomy 4:2 10t. D, 1 Kings 14:8; 2 Kings 18:6
> 5t.; ׳עשׂה מ Leviticus 26:14 (H) + 5 t.; ׳שׁמע מ Deuteronomy 11:13
> 4t.; אשׁר צוּה ׳המ Leviticus 27:34 (H); ׳עבר מ Deuteronomy 26:13;
> 2Chronicles 24:20; ׳עזב מ 1 Kings 18:18; 2 Kings 17:16; Ezra 9:10;
> ׳הפר מ Ezra 9:14; in combinations, especially by Redactors and late
> writers; order various: (1) with חֻקִּים Exodus 15:26 (RD) Deuteronomy
> 4:40; Ezra 7:11 +; ׳ח + משׁפטים Deuteronomy 26:17; 1 Kings 8:58;
> Nehemiah 1:7; Nehemiah 10:30; + משׁפטים, תורות Nehemiah 9:18; + תורה
> Nehemiah 9:14; + עדוֺת Deuteronomy 6:17; 1 Chronicles 29:19;
> 2Chronicles 34:31. (2) with חֻקּוֺת Leviticus 26:3 (H) Deuteronomy
> 6:2; Deuteronomy 10:13 + 9t.; ׳ח + משׁפטים Leviticus 26:15;
> Deuteronomy 8:11; Deuteronomy 11:1; Deuteronomy 30:16; 1 Kings 6:12 +
> תורה, משׁפטים Psalm 89:32, + משׁפטים, עֵדְוֺת 1 Kings 2:3; + תּוֺרוֺת
> Genesis 26:5 (RD); +עדוֺת 2 Kings 23:3. (3) with משׁפטים Numbers 36:13
> (P) 1 Chronicles 28:7; Nehemiah 9:29; Daniel 9:5; with תורות Exodus
> 16:28 (R), with ערות Nehemiah 9:34.
>
> c. of special commands of God 1 Samuel 13:13; 1 Kings 13:21;
> 2Chronicles 29:25; Nehemiah 13:5; Malachi 2:1,4; Job 23:12.
>
> 3 commandment, singular, of code of wisdom Proverbs 19:16, "" תורה
> Proverbs 6:23, "" דבר Proverbs 13:13; plural of special commands
> Proverbs 2:1; Proverbs 3:1; Proverbs 4:4; Proverbs 7:1,2.

Answer (score 1):

Young's Literal Translation Deuteronomy 7:

> 11
> and thou hast kept the **command**, and the statutes, and the judgments, which I am commanding thee to-day to do them.

the command
הַמִּצְוָ֜ה (ham·miṣ·wāh)
Article | Noun - feminine **singular**
Strong's 4687: Commandment

Brown-Driver-Briggs:

> singular the commandment, code of law: 2 Chronicles 8:13; Ezra 10:3; Psalm 19:9

This Hebrew word could mean a code of law, i.e., a collection of related specific regulations.

Brenton Septuagint Translation:

> Thou shalt keep therefore the **commands**, and the ordinances, and these judgments, which I command thee this day to do.

LXX translated it as
ἐντολάς
Parse: Noun: Acc **Plural** Fem
Root: ἐντολή
Strong's 1785

Thayer's Greek Lexicon:

> an order, command, charge, precept

This Greek word in singular does not mean a code of law but a specific regulation.
So, LXX translated the Hebrew idea of a code of law (singular) into the Greek idea of commands (plural).

Why does the [MT] show the singular word מִּצְוָה versus the [LXX] plural word ἐντολὰς?

Because מִּצְוָה = ἐντολὰς

The context bears this out, New International Version:

> Therefore, take care to follow the **commands** [plural], **decrees** [plural] and **laws** [plural] I give you today.

In English, it is clear that Moses was talking about specific individual regulations and not just a code of law in the abstract.